# Compute the hue/saturation/lightness shift between 2 colors for paint.net

Tags: color, color-conversion, paint.net

So, I have a color set up for links on my site.  let's say that color is f80021.  This is for a particular red theme on my site, complete with colored icons, backgrounds for buttons, etc.

What I want to do is take a single color for links from a client and compute the color shift that I can then apply to all the colors, icons, and backgrounds to create a new theme.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What is the relevance of Paint.net in this process and do you require a Paint.net-specific answer?

Comment: It's the application I use and I'm unsure if this calculation would be different for photoshop or other imaging software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This may be a little late, but here's my answer* **:D**

---

I'm not sure if there's an *easier* way, per say, but after looking into it, I think you can do the following.

In Paint.NET, you can expand your **Color** palette with the *More>>* button, this is the first step to finding the equivalent color-shifts for another color, let's say a blue. You will now see the RGB & HSV values. We won't concern ourselves with the RGB values.

### *Red*

Taking your original color of **#F80021**, I created a lighter (**#F77B8C**) and darker versions (**#CC3347**).

What we want to focus on are the HSV values. Below are the HSV values for your original color:

- **Hex**: #F80021
- **H** *(hue)*: 352
- **S** *(saturation)*: 100
- **V** *(value)*: 97

Now for the lighter shade. 
*(NOTE: this is just an example, replace this Hex# with your own, lighter-color version)*

- **Hex**: #F77B8C
- **H** *(hue)*: 352
- **S** *(saturation)*: 50
- **V** *(value)*: 100

And, finally, the darker shade.

- **Hex**: #7F1F2E
- **H** *(hue)*: 352
- **S** *(saturation)*: 75
- **V** *(value)*: 50

Notice that the **hue** values stayed the same throughout the shade changes.

---

### *Blue*

To create a blue theme with similar shades/values as the rest, you first pick a blue. In this case, **#0000F8**. Again, the HSV values are as follows:

- **Hex**: #0000F8
- **H** *(hue)*: 240
- **S** *(saturation)*: 100
- **V** *(value)*: 97

Notice, that this blue's **Saturation** and **Value** amounts are the same as your original red's **Saturation** and **Value** amounts. The same will be true for your lighter and darker blues. *(The lighter blue's **S** & **V** values will match the lighter red's **S** & **V** values, while the  darker blue's will match the darker red's.)*

Lighter blue.

- **Hex**: #7F7FFF
- **H** *(hue)*: 240
- **S** *(saturation)*: 50
- **V** *(value)*: 100

And, the darker blue.

- **Hex**: #1F1F7F
- **H** *(hue)*: 240
- **S** *(saturation)*: 75
- **V** *(value)*: 50

---

### *Conclusion*

So, in short, for your new theme to match your old one, your new **Saturation** & **Value** amounts need to match your old **S** & **V** amounts and for your new theme's color to stay consistent, your **Hue** value needs to be the same in your new theme.

I hope this made sense. If you or someone else has a question, I'll do my best to answer it in the comments.